# Delphi Devart dbExpress driver for Oracle Cloud Direct Mode "ORA-03113:end-of-file on communication channel"

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, devart, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We are currently using Delphi 13.3 and DevArt dbexpress for Oracle 7.2.1.
We are looking to change our Oracle client server database to the the cloud.
We looking into to moving to an Oracle Cloud Autonomous Database via Direct Connect...ie Connection Name = DevArt Oracle Direct.

I can specify the database server in the HostName property of DevartOracleDirect DBX Driver, for example:

```
SQLConnection.Params.Values['HostName'] := '<your OracleTestHostName>:1521:<your service name>';
```

I get the following generic error "ORA-03113:end-of-file on communication channel".

If I take the information from TNS names... I use
test_high = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=xxxx.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=yyyy.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="zzzz")))

```
SQLConnection.Params.Values['HostName'] := 'xxxx.oraclecloud.com:1522:yyyy.oraclecloud.com';
SQLConnection.Params.Values['User_Name'] := 'myUserName';
SQLConnection.Params.Values['Password'] := 'myPassword';
```

I set my SQLConnection to connected=true then I get "ORA-03113:end-of-file on communication channel". I have worked through some various scenarios and appear stuck at this point.
With the Oracle Cloud database am I missing something else ? like including the security/ssl certificate? or the Oracle Cloud Wallet/Client Credentials in the SQLConnection?

On a side note I also have the dbx SQLServer product and do a direct connect to an Azure SQLServer database and all works very easily.

Comment: Last time I looked you needed tunnel over SSH. Basically using SSH to securely tunnel a local port to the Oracle database port on the other end. This lets you connect with a variety of clients without exposing them directly on the Internet. At least for Oracle Database Classic Cloud: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/database-dbaas-cloud/csdbi/create-ssh-tunnel.html#GUID-6929CE39-6CD7-46C9-8022-929A9844B1C5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into this for you I found that you had also posted via the dbExpress forums. It appears that at present, Devart dbExpress Driver for Oracle doesn't support SSL connection in Direct Mode. The Devart teams response can be found here - https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=42351